# Calculate $\int_D x^3y\ dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $D$ the bounded region by the $y$-axis  and the parable $x= -4y^2 + 3$.

How can I calculate the integral $$\int_D x^3y\ dx\,dy$$

I am stuck with this problem some help to solve this please.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Are you having trouble setting up the bounds of the integral? If so, have you sketched the region yet?

Comment: Did you visualise the graph of the area bounded by the curve and y-axis?

Comment: yes i have problems starting this problem im new in integral like this, i don't understand why i have a parable under the integral ?

Comment: Do you know what a double integral is, or could you evaluate it if the bounds were given to you?

Comment: no, sorry for my dumbs question ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(y)=-4y^2 + 3$

This curve intersects with y-axis at $y=\pm \sqrt{3/4}=:\pm B$.
$$\int_D x^3y dxdy=\int_{-B}^{B} \left(\int_{0}^{f(y)} x^3 dx\right) ydy=0$$

This is because:

$$g(y):=\int_{0}^{f(y)} x^3 dx =g(-y)$$

So $g(y) y$ is an odd function of $y$.